# Is there any reason to log old IDs?

Tags: integration, salesforce-id, migration, externalid, id

Recently did an org-to-org migration where the first org's ord-id and other IDs will never be used again; went from one trial, to another trial; second trial was converted to a non-trial account. Is there any reason to archive the IDs from the first trial, which is dead, and have no reason to believe it'll ever be used again, or more importantly, recoverable; not that there would be a reason, just the facts. Further, is there any reason to log old IDs if their either no longer active, or there's no intent to reintegrate the data in the future?

Basically, attempt to confirm that beyond the obvious use of future reintegration if there's a reason that the IDs might be of use; for example, there's meta-data in the IDs that's not present anywhere else that might be of future use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An ID is comprised of four parts:

```
AAA BBB CCCCCCCCC DDD
|   |   |         |
|   |   |         \----- Case Insensitive Modifier (optional)
|   |   \--------------- Auto-Number Base62 (server-unique)
|   \------------------- Origin Server (1=na1, etc)
\----------------------- Entity Key (001=Account, etc)
```

Of all this metadata, there's nothing significant about the ID values. For example, if an org is migrated between servers, the server ID won't match the current server anymore, so it really doesn't matter. For custom objects, the key prefix may no longer match unless the objects were created in the same order.

If you were already integrated with external systems, you might need the old ID value to map to the current record. Since you only had a trial, it's unlikely that you've done enough work to justify trying to work with the old ID values. Just perform a fresh sync, and you're good to go.

While there are times you might want to know information from the ID, such as performing some sort of sync where you want to ignore records created in a sandbox, there's no real reason to keep the ID values around once you've verified all your data was migrated successfully.

Comment: Nice ASCII graph. So, replacing the IDs with new IDs was easy enough, so it seems like there's no reason to log them. Thanks!